# How to blur a transparent texture in a glsl shader?

Tags: glsl, webgl

My setup:

Ping-ponging RGBA FBO's, and two shaders for blurring: a horizontal and a vertical one. Imagine I want to blur a red rectangle.

The blend function is as follows:

```
_gl.blendEquationSeparate(_gl.FUNC_ADD, _gl.FUNC_ADD);
_gl.blendFuncSeparate(_gl.SRC_ALPHA, _gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, _gl.ONE, _gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

In my blur shaders I add several fragments like this:

```
vec4 color = texture2D(u_image, v_tex_coord + vec2(x, y) * u_amount) * weight;
```

Problem:

Blurring works fine on opaque textures, but as it mixes in more and more transparency, the colors become black, as if everything is mixed with a black background. My clear color is `0,0,0,0`, so that makes sense.

Question:

How do I get a blur effect that truly goes to transparent red, instead of a red mixed with more and more black as the alpha goes to zero?

I basically want the same as when you blur something on a complete transparent background in Photoshop. Do I need premultiplied FBO's or do I need to handle the mixing of fragments in the shader differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using premultiplied alpha everywhere.

Being used to how Photoshop works, it took me a while to grasp the concept. It felt a bit counterintuitive, but [this explanation from Tom Forsyth](http://home.comcast.net/~tom_forsyth/blog.wiki.html#%5B%5BPremultiplied%20alpha%5D%5D) helped me a lot.

All my shaders now multiply the RGB values by it's A:

`gl_FragColor = clr.rgb * alpha`;

and I'm using a different blendmode that makes this work:

`_gl.blendEquation(_gl.FUNC_ADD);
_gl.blendFunc(_gl.ONE, _gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`

I had to make sure that my .PNG image textures are also premultiplied. I did that using:

`_gl.pixelStorei(_gl.UNPACK_PREMULTIPLY_ALPHA_WEBGL, true);`

Answer (score 3):

To apply blur to transparent texture you need use alpha to correct. There is simplified formula for one pixel:

```
resultColor = (sum of pixels of input image) * 1 / K;
```

Commonly K is kernel size.

If you blur transparent texture you need accumulate alpha and use it as K.

```
resultAlpha = (sum of alpha pixels of input image);
resultColor = (sum of pixels of input image) * 1 / resultAlpha;
resultAlpha = resultAlpha * 1 / K;
```

For this formula if you blur 4 pixels and one of them is opacity and another is transparent, color of result pixel will be the same, but alpha will be 4 time smaller.

In my example all channels have value form 0 to 1.

Comment: I was indeed using my alpha in the wrong way. I'm going to answer my own question though, because it involves a bit more.